# Error building caffe - undefined reference to cblas_sgemv

Tags: caffe, atlas

I am trying to build caffe using Atlas, CUDA and cuDNN on Fedora 22 and I'm getting this error.

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so
[ 86%] Built target caffe
Linking CXX executable caffe
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sgemv'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sscal'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemv'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_saxpy'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dasum'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dscal'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_scopy'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sasum'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_daxpy'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dcopy'
../lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sdot'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/build.make:109: recipe for target 'tools/caffe' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/caffe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:373: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The fix mentioned [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2348) is to add *opencv_imgcodecs* to the list of libraries but I'm still getting the same error.

Is this problem related to Atlas or is the fix in the Makefile? I had to edit FindAtlas.cmake earlier to get it to find the libraries on my system.